# Find origin given 3 points on a square

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

I am doing a calibration routine with a robot. I search with a sensor for the corner of the square.

[image]

As shown in the picture I get the X,Y of points A,B and C. Now I want to calculate the XY of point D (origin). the corner is always 90 degrees. How do I do that?

I have tried to calculate this on my own but my math skills are letting me down.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to find a point D in the line passing through (A-B), so that  (D-A) is perpendicular to (D-C). My derivation is four lines using vector algebra.

Expanding to scalar arithmetic and implementing in python we have

```py
def corner(a,b,c):
    c1 = (a[0] - c[0]) * (a[0] - b[0]) + (a[1] - c[1]) * (a[1] - b[1])
    c2 = (a[0] - b[0]) * (a[0] - b[0]) + (a[1] - b[1]) * (a[1] - b[1])
    t = c1 / c2
    return [a[0] + (b[0] - a[0])*t, a[1] + t * (b[1] - a[1])]
```

```py
corner((3,5), (5,9), (-1, 2)) // should give (1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def locate_vertex(A, B, C):
    AB = B - A
    AB = AB / np.sqrt((AB).dot(AB))
    D = A + (C-A).dot(AB)*AB
    return D
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.